# How can I get custom pod scheduling on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to implement custom scheduling semantics for a cluster running on Google Container Engine (specifically, I'd like to make use of MostRequestedPriority that was added circa 1.5)

I understand from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/758531/update-scheduling-policy-configuration)  that one cannot configure GKE's kube-schedule, as it is out-of-reach.

My next guess was to try deploying [multiple Kubernetes schedulers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/multiple-schedulers/), but following the guide, pods that request the second scheduler don't get scheduled, and the scheduler pod warns:

```
2017-02-06T20:59:57.653394031Z W0206 20:59:57.653076 1 client_config.go:481] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
2017-02-06T20:59:57.710633908Z I0206 20:59:57.710463 1 leaderelection.go:247] lock is held by gke-658313547898-12d2ae9e593b23f9af1a and has not yet expired
2017-02-06T21:00:01.165367631Z I0206 21:00:01.165169 1 leaderelection.go:247] lock is held by gke-658313547898-12d2ae9e593b23f9af1a and has not yet expired
...
```

Is this currently possible at all, and if so, how should I approach it?

Comment: Your scheme should work, but your custom scheduler is attempting to grab the same lock that the default scheduler uses (the scheduler is written to run in an active / hot standby configuration). You'll need to either need to change a flag or (more likely) rebuild the scheduler to change the lock it wants to use.